# Does anyone know why am I getting a fetch_array() boolean error?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to fetch TaxRate data from a table and I'm trying to select the first array only. However, I keep getting this error

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array()
> on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php:77 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowerique\shoppingCart.php
> on line 77"

Does anyone know the cause of this error and how do I fix it? Thanks!

This is my code :

```
        //Retrieve Current GST Pricing 
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM gst GROUP BY EffectiveDate DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($qry);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$stmt->close();
        $result = $conn->query($qry);    
        $row = $result->fetch_array();       // This is line 77 
        while($row["EffectiveDate"] < date("Y-m-d"))
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
        }
        $currentTaxRate = $row["TaxRate"];
```

[image: Image of SQL Table]

Comment: I have tried the SQL Query and can confirm that it works.

Comment: Change `SELECT * FROM gst GROUP BY EffectiveDate DESC` to `SELECT * FROM gst ORDER BY EffectiveDate DESC` and always check the result from the `$conn->query($qry)` call.

Comment: Why do you call `execute()` __and__ `query()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param) P.S. Droopsnoot is right, you are executing the query twice, for no apparent reason. If you aren't accepting user input into this query then there's no value in using prepared statements.